# why are the prerequisites not set as expected?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write this `makefile` where the prerequisites for a target should be the output of a shell command. here's what I have

```
foo: ($shell find mydir -name "*.ext")
    # command goes here
```

where `mydir` is a directory under the same directory where the `makefile` itself. however, executing `make foo` executes the recipes even if none of the `*.ext` files were modified (i.e., it always executes the recipes acting as if there are prerequisites set).

I'm sure that the `find` command outputs the expected results.

any idea what might be going wrong here and how to get it to behave expectedly?

Comment: You didn't copy/paste the first line of the recipe, since it has a typo that would prevent it from working. Are you sure the rule is producing a file called "foo"?

Comment: @Beta the recipe executes. the problem is that it always executes as I make the target no matter whether the prerequisites were modified or not.

Comment: @Kareem As @Beta said: "Are you sure the rule is producing a file called `foo`?". If not, the rule will always be executed, trying to create the `foo` file even if the prerequisites are OK.

Comment: @jml maybe I miss-interpreted @Beta's comment. well, it actually produced many files among which was `foo`. apparently the problem was that `foo` was not produced in the same directory as the `makefile`. thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little test to see if it is working. Here the `Makefile`:

```
foo: $(shell find mydir -name "*.ext")
    cat $^ > $@
```

And the file tree:

```
.
├── Makefile
└── mydir
    ├── bar.ext
    └── foo.ext
```

Then run the `Makefile`:

```
$ make
cat mydir/foo.ext mydir/bar.ext > foo
$ make
make: `foo' is up to date.
$ touch mydir/foo.ext
$ make
cat mydir/foo.ext mydir/bar.ext > foo
```

So it's working well. Just be sure that your `foo` file is created by the build rule.